# how to use Optional isPresent() properly

Tags: java, spring-data-jpa

I have this method:

```java
public String updateShift(ShiftsDTO shiftsDTO){

    Optional<Shifts> optionalPreUpdateShift = shiftsRepository.findById(shiftsDTO.getId());

    if (optionalPreUpdateShift.isPresent()) {
        if (!shiftsRepository.existsByShiftStartAndShiftEnd(shiftsDTO.getShiftStart(), shiftsDTO.getShiftEnd())) {
            Shifts preUpdateShift = optionalPreUpdateShift.get();
            shiftsMapper.mapShiftFromDto(shiftsDTO,preUpdateShift);
            shiftsRepository.save(preUpdateShift);
            return " Shift updated successfully";
        } else {
            throw new ShiftAlreadyExistsException("An existing shift already covers this period");
        }
    } else {
        throw  new ShiftNotFoundException("This shift doesn't exist");
    }
}
```

This method is for updating shifts in a shop. I didn't use isPresent() before and now tried to implement it but the code looks incredibly dirty and unreadable. What are the correct ways to use Optional in such cases?

Comment: `shiftsRepository.findById(shiftsDTO.getId()).orElseThrow(() ->  new ShiftNotFoundException("This shift doesn't exist"));  ` then you can remove the outer if else block

Comment: I tend to agree with the OP in general though, `Optional` makes code look worse. If you simply document a `null` result, it should be enough.  The extra code doesn't add enough value over simply requiring a human to read the docs.  (I'm ignoring the idea that `Shifts` plural should perhaps be its own container and never `null`.  `Optional` doesn't fix problems with the domain model.)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One way to keep yourself from indenting like this: Change your first line

```java
Optional<Shifts> optionalPreUpdateShift = ShiftsRepository.findById(shiftsDTO.getId());
```

to instead unwrap the optional right away:

```java
Shifts shifts = ShiftsRepository.findById(shiftsDTO.getId())
                .orElseThrow(()-> new ShiftNotFoundException("This shift doesn't exist");
```

Comment: right, hmm.. actually a string is expected from the method finally, so probably encapsulate the inner if-else into a method (e.g. `updateShift(...)`), then calling `map(...)` after retrieving the Optional, would better suit.

e.g. 
`String result = ShiftsRepository.findById(shiftsDTO.getId()).map(preUpdateShift -> updateShift(preUpdateShift, ...)).orElseThrow(()-> new ShiftNotFoundException("This shift doesn't exist");`

Comment: Marked as the answer. I'll unwrap optional instead of going through isPresent().

Answer (score 0):

I would extract the inner logic of your `if...else` statement into its own private method.  Then you can do something like this, which has the added bonus of improved readability as well.

```java
  public String updateShift(ShiftsDTO shiftsDTO)
  {
    return shiftsRepository.findById(shiftsDTO.getId()).map(preUpdateShift -> doUpdate(preUpdateShift, shiftsDTO))
        .orElseThrow(() -> new ShiftNotFoundException("This shift doesn't exist"));
  }

  private String doUpdate(Shifts preUpdateShift, ShiftsDTO shiftsDTO)
  {
    if (!shiftsRepository.existsByShiftStartAndShiftEnd(shiftsDTO.getShiftStart(), shiftsDTO.getShiftEnd()))
    {
      shiftsMapper.mapShiftFromDto(shiftsDTO, preUpdateShift);
      shiftsRepository.save(preUpdateShift);
      return " Shift updated successfully";
    }
    else
    {
      throw new ShiftAlreadyExistsException("An existing shift already covers this period");
    }
  }
```

Comment: A bit messy don't you think?